# Logic and floats, 0.75 > 0 = false?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, int, parseint

In Javascript I have an if statement that is failing that should be passing and I cannot figure out why. Here's the structure of the if.

```
if(parseInt(obj.OptionCredit) > parseInt(Account.Credits))
{
     true
}
else

{
     false
}
```

When I console log the two variables I get Account.Credits = 0 and obj.OptionCredit = 0.75. With that said, 0.75 > 0 should return false.

Can anyone help me out with this? Thank you!

Comment: parseInt(0.75) = 0, parseFloat(0.75) = 0.75

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are parsing them as ints (not floats), so they both return zero. 0 is not greater than 0, so the comparison returns false.

Comment: I changed it to parseFloat() and it worked. For months the system worked with only whole numbers so parseInt worked but I didn't catch that. Thanks! Needed another set of eyes on it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `parseFloat()` instead of `parseInt()`